# What is the fastest way to deconstruct a fixed length binary/alpha message?

Tags: c++, parsing

What would you suggest as the fastest or best way to parse a fixed length message in c++ which has fields defined like

```
field = 'type', length = 2, type = 'alphanumeric'

field = 'length', length = 2, type = 'binary' (edit:length = 2 means 16 bit)
...
...

and so on
```

I read about making a struct and then using reinterpret_cast but im not sure how to use that or if there is any better method.

By parsing, i mean extracting human readable format like 'Type = X', 'Length = 15' etc

Comment: If possible, try using a look-up table loaded into memory.  Simple comparisons are much faster than decoding.

Comment: What are the semantics of the binary type? Does `length=2` mean any 16-bit quantity or 00-99?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
char* binaryMessage; //From somewhere
struct Fields {
    short type; // 2 bytes
    short length; // 2 bytes
};
Fields* fields = reinterpret_cast<Fields*>(binaryMessage);
std::cout << "Type = " << fields->type;
std::cout << "Length = " << fields->length;
```

A safer alternative is [`boost::basic_bufferstream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/interprocess/streams.html#interprocess.streams.bufferstream):

```
basic_bufferstream<char> stream(binaryMessage, lengthOfMessage, std::ios_base::in);
Fields fields;
stream >> fields.type;
stream >> fields.length;
```

Comment: This is one way though but is it really safe since reinterpret_cast is considered pretty dangerous to use